# How to properly construct a if statement in SQL Server procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL `if` statement in a stored procedure, it's going to be something like this:

```
...........
if B is not null{
  if A is null{
    insert B to database
  }
  else if A != B but A is not null{
    update B to replace A
  }
  else(when A = B){
     do nothing
  }
}
.....other codes.....
```

My problem is I don't know how to write "do nothing" in A = B scenario, is there any way to properly construct this if statement? Or should I just use two if with conditions?

Comment: I don't know if the final else is required, I have never tried to leave it out. But you can certainly have an empty block for the final else, so it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I tried to leave an empty else block but apparently sql server does not allow empty block inside if statement.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a MERGE to me but hard to tell from so little details.

Answer (score 3):

You can just omit the `ELSE` part of the `IF...ELSE` statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

The brackets around the `ELSE` mean it's optional.

I recommend you read the other subjects about [Control-of-Flow Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try not to wrap that kind of logic around SQL. I would get rid of the ifs altogether.

```
insert into <table> (<fields>)
    SELECT B
    WHERE B is not null
    AND A is null

UPDATE <table>
SET <field>=B
WHERE A is not null
AND B is not null
AND A <> B
AND <field>=A
```

A MERGE statement would work as well.